# AngularJS: http request does not return anything

Tags: angularjs, rest, http

I wanted to build a simple page for query with an input box and a button. Here is my html:

```
<html ng-app="cgApp" >
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/service.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="CgseqCtrl">
        <input ng-model="analysisid"><button ng-click="searchById()">Search</button>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>{{seq.analysisId}}</td>
                <td>{{seq.center}}</td>
                <td>{{seq.diseaseAbbr}}</td>
                <td>{{seq.filepath}}</td>
                <td>{{seq.library}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Function to handle ng-click event `searchById()` is implemented in my controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('cgApp', [])

app.controller('CgseqCtrl', ['$scope', 'Cgseq', function($scope, Cgseq){
    $scope.searchById = function() {
        Cgseq.getSeqById($scope.analysisid)
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.seq = response;
        }, function errorCallBack(response) {
            console.log(response.$statusText);
        });
    }
}]);
```

`Cgseq` is name of my factory in service.js.

```
app.factory("Cgseq", function ($http) {
    // return $resource('http://localhost:8080/cgweb/api/seqs/fdebfd6e-d046-4192-8b97-ac9f65dc2009');
    var service = {};
    service.getSeqById = function(analysisid) {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/cgweb/api/seqs/' + analysisid);
    }
    return service;
});
```

When I load basic.html, type in the string for query and click the button, nothing happens in the page. I tried to debug step by step, it turns out it never got into `.then` or `function errorCallBack`. Nothing from logs of node.js server or tomcat server looks suspicious. What did I do wrong?

EDIT #1:

Based on the network status, it looks like connection to server is good (200).
[image: network tab]

Comment: Does the server actually receive the request? And if so, what do you see in the network tab of your browser's web inspector?

Comment: check the network calls in the developer console

Comment: @SunilD. I have uploaded screenshot of network tab. The bottom line shows the server has received the request, right?

Comment: @war1oc Screenshot added to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cgseq.getSeqById($scope.analysisid)
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.seq = response.data; // You have to use response.data
        }, function errorCallBack(response) {
            console.log(response.$statusText);
        });
```

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

If you do a `console.log(response)` in the then callback you can see the structure of the response object.